# теория Базы Данных

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте скажите грамотно ли получилось создать базу данных ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Добавлять новые колонки кроме тех что здесь нельзя .

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретных критериев «грамотной» базы, от целей её использования, от частоты определённых запросов к ней

Comment: Если цель — сдать зачёт и забыть поскорее про этот ужас, то возможно даже сойдёт

Comment: Просто как начинающему хотелось бы узнать , именно вот тут  как я построил БД , может считаться правильным , нету каких то ошибок ?